# Exact match with str_locate regex in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I tried to am trying to run an if() conditional on someone being in the US senate ... but I get the wrong results, because I cannot match exactly in R. I tried word boundaries \b and beginning/end ^$, but it doesn't seem to work .... and do not know why?

```
> splits[[1]][4]
[1] "Ohio State Senate, 1979-1983"
> is.numeric(str_locate(splits[[1]][4], "\bSenator\b"))
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(str_locate(splits[[1]][4], "/^Senator$/"))
[1] TRUE
> pattern <- "\bSenator\b"
> is.numeric(str_locate(splits[[1]][4], pattern))
[1] TRUE
```

Basically, the above should all yield false as my data only uses Senator if it is the US Senate, not a state senate.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Walter

Comment: Perhaps you want `str_detect`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x<-"Ohio State Senate, 1979-1983"
kk<-unlist(strsplit(x," "))
kk %in% state.name
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

OR,

```
is.numeric(str_locate(x, state.name)) #If this is true, then the senator is state senator
```

Comment: Thank you. Using this to read out the state now too, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The function works as expected, you are just surprised by the return type. If it doesn't find a match then `NA` is returned. More specifically, an `NA_integer_` is returned (which take the maximum negative value for an integer of -2147483648).

```
x <- "Ohio State Senate, 1979-1983"
str_locate( x , "\bSenator\b")
#     start end
#[1,]    NA  NA
#[2,]    NA  NA
```

And an `NA_integer_` is actually a numeric...

```
is.numeric( NA_integer_ )
#[1] TRUE
```

So it all works fine. Try `!all( is.na( str_locate( x , "\bSenator\b") ) )` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me but without the \b's for word boundaries. I didn't realise NA_integer_ existed, my bad ... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The help docs for `str_locate` specify that it returns an integer matrix. Playing with the function a little, on a non match, it returns `NA`.

You can test against NA:

```
> library(stringr)
> v <- "Ohio State Senate, 1979-1983"

> str_locate(v, "\\bSenator\\b")
start end
[1,]    NA  NA
> is.na(str_locate(v, "\\bSenator\\b")[,c('start')])
start
TRUE

> str_locate(v, "Senate")
start end
[1,]    12  17
> is.na(str_locate(v, "Senate")[,c('start')])
start
FALSE
```

Personally, I'd just use grep:

```
> grep("Senate",v)
integer(1)
> grep("Senator",v)
integer(0)
```

If you want to use word boundary matches you need to escape the slash: `\\b`, not `\b`.